# EF Core relationships between 3 tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have table Orders that has Orderid as primary key and patient id as foreign key. My second table is Patients table has Patient id as primary key. There is a third table OrderPatient which has only order id as the foreign key but it has all patient details (such as patient first name last name etc). OrderPatient table doesnt have patientid as foreign key. I am working on EF core using existing database. I am trying to customize the orderpatient model to have Patientdetails property of Patients class as shown below. But since there is no patient id as key in OrderPatient table, i am unable to establish the relationship in context class. How to establish the relationship between OrderPatient and Patient class and populate Patientdetails when accessing OrderPatient model.

I tried using the efcore relationships and navigation properties.

```
    public partial class Orders
{

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Patients Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderPatient OrderPatient { get; set; }

}


public partial class Patients
{

    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Orders> Orders { get; set; }

}

 public partial class OrderPatient
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }       
    public Patients PatientDetails { get; set; }
    public int? OptHeight { get; set; }
    public int? OptWeight { get; set; }
    public string OptPrimaryLanguage { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
  }
```

I am trying to customize the orderpatient model to have Patientdetails property of Patients class as shown below. But since there is no patient id as key in OrderPatient table, i am unable to establish the relationship in context class. How to establish the relationship between OrderPatient and Patient class and populate Patientdetails when accessing OrderPatient model.

Answer (score 0):

Add a navigation property on your Order Patient table for Order.

```
public partial class OrderPatient
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }       
    public Patients PatientDetails { get; set; } //Remove this
    public int? OptHeight { get; set; }
    public int? OptWeight { get; set; }
    public string OptPrimaryLanguage { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }// Add this
}
```

And on your Order Table

```
public partial class Orders
{

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Patients Patient { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderPatient OrderPatient { get; set; }// Remove this

}
```

Then access the Patient table from OrderPatient.

```
orderPatient.Order.Patient
```

Since you are using lazy loading. I think this will work. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the navigation property in OrderPatient for Order. OrderPatient table has patient details such as patient first, last name etc which are specific to an order. Patient table also has these columns. So I am using Patients model as type for PatientDetails property in OrderPatient. But I am getting run time exception when trying to get details as shown below.

Comment: var orderdetails = ctxt.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderId == 4072281)
                 .Include(o => o.Patient)
                 .Include(o => o.OrderPatient)
                 .Include(o => o.OrderPatient.PatientDetails).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Based on your post, no, you do not have. You only have the OrderId on OrderPatient table. Look again.

Comment: My question here is how to edit the context class so i get data for PatientDetails

Comment: I am getting thisexception. System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'PatientDetails' is not a navigation property of entity type 'OrderPatient'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.'